# PayPal IPN response empty

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been trying for the last 5 hours to debug this problem and/or find answers online, and all for naught. I'm testing in the sandbox, but the same problem exists on the live server, which suggests it's something wrong with my code rather than the sandbox, but I cannot figure out what that thing is. My code is basically copied directly from the PayPal example [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/).

```
// Step 2: POST IPN data back to PayPal to validate
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
    error_log("Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    mail($notifyemail,'CURL error on IPN',"Got " . curl_error($ch) . " when processing IPN data");
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

(I left out everything above this code for brevity, but rest assured that all code before this is tested and verified to be working properly. I have tested with both string and array for `$req`)

When testing in the sandbox, it says `IPN was sent and the handshake was verified` (suggesting to me that port 443 is open). However, $res is always empty. Even stranger, during my debugging I added a step where my code emails me the contents of `curl_getinfo($ch)` both before and after the `curl_exec()` step, and in both of those cases, everything except the url is also empty - as if the options aren't being added to the request at all. I'm not experienced enough with curl to know whether that's normal.

PayPal says of the IPN:

```
HTTP response code: 200
Delivery status: Sent
No. of retries: 0
IPN type: Transaction made
```

I tried swapping in the library from https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN and using that instead, and it logged `cURL error: [7]` (unable to connect) which doesn't make any sense to me, since the handshake was again verified. I emailed the contents of `$listener->getTextReport()` to myself, but it does not include any error information at all.

Trying various combinations of `use_ssl` and `use_curl`, my error log looks like this:

```
[05-Oct-2016 16:40:13 America/Toronto] cURL error: [7] 
[05-Oct-2016 16:47:22 America/Toronto] PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443 (Operation not permitted) in /home/[stuff]/public_html/[stuff]/ipnlistener.php on line 144
[05-Oct-2016 16:47:22 America/Toronto] fsockopen error: [1] Operation not permitted
[05-Oct-2016 16:50:39 America/Toronto] cURL error: [7] 
[05-Oct-2016 16:51:55 America/Toronto] PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to www.sandbox.paypal.com:80 (Operation not permitted) in /home/[stuff]/public_html/[stuff]/ipnlistener.php on line 144
[05-Oct-2016 16:51:55 America/Toronto] fsockopen error: [1] Operation not permitted
```

There must be something I'm getting wrong or overlooking, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what that could be. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the problem was that the webhost hadn't whitelisted www.sandbox.paypal.com. So, a lesson to anyone else who's encountering this problem: check with your webhost to make sure everything is actually in place to let you do what you need to do.

Sidenote: Now that I have experience with it, I recommend the IPN library I started using at the end of the day. The ability to quickly switch between test and live environments, and between cURL and sockets, is incredibly useful and beneficial, and it made testing significantly faster towards the end of my day.